# Opera, event.layerX / event.layerY properties and mouseDropped event

Tags: javascript, events, mouse, raphael, opera

I am writing some application with [Raphael.js](http://raphaeljs.com). And it should handle mouse drag events.

That is, when mouse drag is ended, i try to catch the point on the Raphael's `Paper` object (`DIV` / `SVG` element, actually) where the mouse caused `drop` event.

*FireFox* and *Chrome* are doing well with `event.layerX` and `event.layerY` properties. But *Opera* does not have those.

It has `clientX` / `clientY`, `offsetX` / `offsetY` and `pageX` / `pageY` properties (may be mistaken in the last two' names) however. But i can't create any algorithm to calculate the final mouse position.

See, the mouse starts "dragging" pin of an circuit symbol (without actual dragging its image) and ends dropping on another one:

[image]
[image]

So, *Opera* shows coordinates like *(5, 7)* when mouse causes *drop* event. I assume these are the coordinates around the second pin. But i do not need those - using them i can not find the pin user tries connect to.

**So, the questionis:** do you know any way to find the mouse cursor coordinates when the *drop* event is called, relatively to the parent element it is dropping (e.g. Raphael's `Paper` object and / or its container in the case described).

Comment: check this page for visual understanding of different mouse event properties http://www.gtalbot.org/DHTMLSection/WindowEventsO7.html

Answer (score 0):

Can you keep updating variables with the location of the cursor during mouse move when the mouse button is down and use the last values set when the drop is fired?

Comment: That's what i am doing right now. The question is: how to get the mouse cursor' coordinates using `MouseEvent` argument in Opera.